# Как вывести только строчные русские буквы.С#

Tags: c#, строки

Дана строка которую выбираем в `listBox1` нужно что бы в `label1` выводились только  строчные русские буквы. Как это можно сделать не используя `char` и `foreach`, просто получается только с ними.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rab_1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
           string str = (string)listBox1.Items[index];
          
           char[] a = { 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё','ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я' };
           
           foreach (char ch in str)
           {
               if (Array.IndexOf(a, ch) >= 0)
                   label1.Text += (ch);
           }
           

       }
       
       
   }
}
```

Comment: Если открыть таблицу символов, то можно увидеть, что символы от `a` до `я` идут подряд и только `ё` идет после `я` через символ. Таким образом можно обойтись `if((ch >= 'а' && ch <= 'я') ||  ch == 'ё')`

Comment: @Bulson `if (ch != ch.ToUpper())`

Comment: @aepot ‍♂️ ну, да, ну да...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто в копилку вариантов

```
var str = "lkjlkjдодлодДЛОДЛО;lk;lkждл1ёжлЖДЛЖЛ;lk;lkждлждл;kl:KLДД";   
var str2 = string.Concat(str.Where(c=>c >= 'а' && c <= 'я' || c == 'ё'));
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

Вывод

```
додлодждлёжлждлждл
```